# Handling a Spring Integration MessageHandler that returns a Flux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-integration-dsl

My message handler returns a flux and ideally, I want spring integration to handle blocking/subscribing to the flux so that my second handler below gets the resolved object. But when the following code runs the output is: `FluxFlatMap`

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
      Function<Map,Flux<Account>> handler = (map)->service.getAccounts(map)
                .take(20)
                .log()
                .flatMap(account -> orderService.getOrdersForAcct(account).take(3));

      return IntegrationFlow.from("accountMessageChannel")
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Map.class))
                .handle((payload,headers)-> handler.apply(payload))
                .handle((payload,headers)->{log.info("got something");log.info(payload.toString());return null;})
                .get();
}
```

I have tried passing off the Flux to a FluxMessageChannel but the behavior was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was fixed recently in the current development branch: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-6.0-to-6.1-Migration-Guide#endpoint-is-async-by-default-for-output-channel-as-fluxmessagechannel.

So, to make it working and resolving your `Flux` reply, you need to do this with the version you are using:

```
.handle((payload,headers)-> handler.apply(payload), e -> e.async(true))
```

Comment: Thankyou! that fixed it. I had to send the result of the handler to a FluxMessageChannel

Comment: That's correct. Otherwise the whole payload is treated as a payload to be sent. Only `FluxMessageChannel` does flattening of the reactive reply: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/reactive-streams.html#reactive-reply-payload